# How to convert from base 4 to base 16?

Tags: number-systems

I have the number 10011100010101 from base 4  and I need to conv in base 16. I wrote the number in pairs of 2 and tried to write it as such 0×16^0+1×16^1.. from left to right is it correct this way?

Comment: What kind of a mutated oddity is a base $4$ number with nothing but zeroes and ones? Seems like it really wants to be binary.

Comment: It's a 4 in this book...

Comment: One hexadecimal digit can be represented by 2 base 4 digits.

Answer (score 2):

$16 = 4^2$, so try splitting the number into blocks of two and convert those blocks separately

Comment: Thta's what I did too but I wasn't sure if it's correct,thank you.

Comment: @Lola you can use an online converter to check your answer...

Answer (score 0):

In general you'll want to go from right to left with the blocks.

In this case, it doesn't matter whether you go left to right or right to left, but if you have an odd number of digits, you'll miss the leading zero and have to do it all again.